# Object required?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function openEditor(){
        $("#editor").show().animate({width: 965, height: 380}, 1500);
        $("#editor textarea").show();
    }

    function closeEditor(){
        $("#editor").animate({width: 985, height: 1}, 1500, function(){
            $("#editor").hide();
            $("#editor textarea").hide();
        });
    }

    function setedit(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine.php",
            data: "title="+ $('#editorTitle').attr('value') +"&text="+ $('#editorText').html(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#mainField').html('<img src="data/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading...">');
            },
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
                closeEditor();
                search();
            }
        });
    }
    function search(){ // Row 138
        $('#editorTitle').val($('#search').val());

        $('#mainField').html('<img src="data/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading...">');

        $.get('engine.php?search='+ $('#search').val() , function(data) {
            $('#mainField').html(data);
        });

        $.get('engine.php?raw=true&search='+ $('#search').val() , function(data2) {
            $('#editorText').html(data2);
        });

        $.get('engine.php?title=true&search='+ $('#search').val() , function(data2) {
            $('#h1').html(data2); // Row 152
            $('#editorTitle').html(data2);
        });
    }

    $("#ready").html('Document ready at '+ event.timeStamp); // Row 157

});
```

Hello,

At row 138 and row 157 i get some strange error that an object (?) is required?
I've been working on it all day and it still isn't working...

Help! Please!

Greetings!

Comment: What's `event` (your row 157)? isn't referenced anywhere else...

Comment: Does $('#ready') actually find anything? Is event defined at that point?

Comment: So here's a question for you. These functions are giving you errors. Some of the functions call others, but you haven't shown any code that initially calls any one of these. What have you omitted from the code in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use jQuery's `event.timeStamp` from functions that pass through an event argument, i.e. `click`. So you'll need to get the timeStamp yourself in this case. So change line 157 from:

```
$("#ready").html('Document ready at '+ event.timeStamp); // Row 157
```

to (if you want a timestamp, i.e. number of ms since 1/1/1970):

```
$("#ready").html('Document ready at '+ new Date().getTime());
```

Or (if you want the actual date/time):

```
$("#ready").html('Document ready at '+ new Date.now());
```

[Working fiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4LFt5/)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping all of your code withing the ready() context. You only need to wrap your start-up code in there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init() //or whatever
}
```

.. your code ..

Comment: Unless those functions need to be called globally, I'd keep them where they are so you're not polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Looking @ 157,

```
$("#ready").html('Document ready at '+ event.timeStamp); // Row 157
```

will fail if there is no element with id="ready" on load.

Comment: It won't throw an error.  If there are no results from the jQuery selector, `.html` just does nothing - no error at all.

Comment: @Andy: yup, that's the `Null Object Pattern` hard at work. However - **it will throw an error** trying to resolve the `timeStamp` property of an `undefined` object to pass as a parameter `.html()`!